# Why is $ \sum_{k = 1}^{n - 1}O\left( \binom{n}{k}k^2 \right) = O(n^22^n)$?

Tags: summation, algorithms, asymptotics, binomial-coefficients

In the analysis of an exact dynamic programming analysis for the Travelling Salesman problem in [Exact Exponential Algorithms](http://www.ii.uib.no/~fomin/BookEA/index.html) by Fomin and Kratsch, it is stated on p. 6 that

$$ \sum_{k = 1}^{n - 1}O\left( \binom{n}{k}k^2 \right) = O(n^22^n)$$

**I would like some help to see why this is true.** I understand that

$$ \sum_{k = 1}^{n - 1} \binom{n}{k} = O(2^n) \qquad \text{and} \qquad \sum_{k = 1}^{n - 1} k^2 = O(n^3) $$

I figure the former in particular is relevant, but I can't see how multiplying by the $k^2$ term inside the sum gets the $n^2$ term in the right-hand side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Big - O notation is additive, so you just need to prove:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k}k^2 = O(n^22^n).$$
Note that you don't even need to explicitly calculate the sum, though it is possible. 
Here is a start: 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k}k^2\leq \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k}n^2=...$$

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: after reading [the first](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2958462/why-is-sum-k-1n-1o-left-binomnkk2-right-on22n/2958512#comment6108314_2958512) and [second comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2958462/why-is-sum-k-1n-1o-left-binomnkk2-right-on22n/2958512#comment6108317_2958512) of @MishaLavrov I decided to change accordingly my answer and remove inaccuracy regarding the bounding constant.

An approach to the solution to the problem could be this: first remember that
$$
f(n,k)=O\left(\binom{n}{k}k^2\right)\iff |\,f(n,k)|\le M\binom{n}{k}k^2
$$
where $M$ is an absolute bounding constant. Despite not being clearly stated in Fomin & Kratsch book, $n$ and $k$ must be allowed to go to $\infty$: intuitively this is due to the fact that $n$ expresses the number of cities, i.e. the effective difficulty of the task, while the  $k$ expresses the result of partial travel optimization, thus the complexity depends on both. Now we can infer that
$$
\left|\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}f(n,k)\right|=\left|\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}O\left(\binom{n}{k}k^2\right)\right|\le M\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k}k^2\iff \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}O\left(\binom{n}{k}k^2\right)=O\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k}k^2\right)
$$
Finally, it is an interesting exercise (which can be proved by mathematical induction) that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k}k^2=(n-1)n2^{n-3}=O(n^2 2^n)
$$
and this should answer to the question.

Comment: You don’t need induction to prove this result. Just use the binomial theorem.

Comment: The authors of the book were sloppy about their $O$-notation: they didn't say which variable(s) go to infinity. In particular, $\sum_{k = 1}^{n - 1}O\left( \binom{n}{k}k^2 \right) = O(n^22^n)$ is true if $O\left( \binom{n}{k}k^2 \right)$ is meant with respect to both $n$ and $k$. You're assuming that $O\left( \binom{n}{k}k^2 \right)$ is meant with respect to $n$ alone, in which case things go wrong: your $\overline{M}_n$ is not necessarily constant with respect to $n$, for example if $M_k = 2^k$.

Comment: Interpreting $O\left( \binom{n}{k}k^2 \right)$ as intended, we actually have $f(n,k) = O\left( \binom{n}{k}k^2 \right)  \iff |f(n,k)| \le M \binom nk k^2$ for an absolute constant $M$, and then we proceed as you do, but without having to take a maximum.

Comment: @MishaLavrov: thanks for pointing out the inaccuracies in my answer. When I wrote it I overlooked completely the fact that the existence of an absolute bound $M$  for $\binom{n}{k}k^2$ was implied by its statement, being necessary that both $n,k\to \infty$ strictly keeping the relationship $k\le n$. I will change my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Thiking. Yes, there is no need to use induction: its only that I proved the result as an exercise in my textbook of mathematical analysis, where it was required to prove it by induction. The formula can be proved in the easiest way one knows.

Answer (score 1):

The use of $\mathcal O$-notation in this text bothers me somewhat, because it is sloppy about specifying which variables are going to infinity. So this is a bit of a nonstandard answer. The entire first paragraph of p.6 could be changed to:

> Let us come back to $\texttt{TSP}$. The amount of steps required to compute (1.1) for a
>   fixed set $S$ of size $\le n$ and all vertices $c_i \in S$ is $\mathcal O(n^2)$. The algorithm computes (1.1) for all subsets $S$ of cities, which is $2^n$ computations of (1.1). Therefore the total time to compute $OPT$ is $$\mathcal O(n^2) \cdot 2^n = \mathcal O(n^2 2^n).$$

This should be easier to understand; it avoids any use of the binomial theorem and avoids writing $\mathcal O$-expressions with respect to two non-constant variables.